# How to implement in-app purchase to disable ads in TWA

Tags: in-app-purchase, ads, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

I would like to add advertisements (Interstitial from admob) to my trusted-web-activity and the possibility to disable ads by buying an in-app 'Remove ads' product. The ad-screen should for example be opened each time a user wants to add a new favorite bus stop.

I thought of an activity which some how would listen to the current url and handles opening the advertisements based on the url action and if the user has bought 'Remove ads' or not.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Chrome 88, you can use Google Play Billing with Trusted Web Activity. The documentation for this integration is available [here](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/receive-payments-play-billing).